# Adding geom_point to ggridges

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges

If I want to add a point estimate to a `ggridge` object, but I keep getting an error:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

iris_med <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(Sepal.Length = median(Sepal.Length))

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, fill = 0.5 - abs(0.5-..ecdf..))) +
  stat_density_ridges(geom = "density_ridges_gradient", calc_ecdf = TRUE) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, color = "red"), data = iris_med)

Picking joint bandwidth of 0.181
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'ecdf' not found
```

Output I am hoping to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be solved by specifying `inherit.aes = F` in the `geom_point` call:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, fill = 0.5 - abs(0.5-..ecdf..))) +
  stat_density_ridges(geom = "density_ridges_gradient", calc_ecdf = TRUE) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, color = "red"), data = iris_med, inherit.aes = F)
```

produces just he following message:

`Picking joint bandwidth of 0.181`

[image]

EDIT: Another approach (thanks to @Axeman's comment) would be to move the the `fill` aesthetic to `stat_density_ridges` layer.

Comment: Or move the `fill` aesthetic to `stat_density_ridges`.